# Why is my car pointer going slightly down and then, when accelerating from 2500rpm to 3000 rpm

Tags: vw, diesel, rpm, polo

I just bought Volkswagen polo 2002 diesel with 75 hp 1.4 engine.

The problem is that when i accelerate above 2500 rpm till 3000 rpm, the rpm seems to jump slightly down and then up again, it feels like car has lost power for half of second. Slightly jump also feels on the car so its not problem in pointing.

This is more noticable in third, fourth and fifth gear.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does the car slow down at the same time? Or do you continue to speed up during this period?

Comment: Thank you :) yes, it does slow down but only for a very little like 2-3 k/ph. and for 0.5-1s

Comment: Does it happen no matter how hard you are accelerating?

Comment: Is this a manual or automatic transmission?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your clutch plate is worn and likely due for replacement.  If so, this problem will become progressively worse with use.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a sticky turbo actuator.  There are several things that could cause this.

If the problem was a slipping clutch, you would notice the slippage more in 5th gear when commanding more torque.